# Proof explanation: Why is $(f \circ \gamma)'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))(\gamma '(t))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble understanding the proof that my teacher showed us to the following proposition:

> Let $D\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, $f: D \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function, and $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ be an interval. let $\gamma:I\to \mathbb R^3$ be a differentiable function such that $\gamma(I) \subseteq N_c = \{p \in D: f(p)=c\}$, with $c \in \mathbb R$. Then:$$\forall t \in I: \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) = 0$$
> Where $\nabla f(p)$ is the gradient of $f$ at the point $p$.

The proof he gave is the following:

$\forall t \in I, f(\gamma(t)) = c$, so if we differentiate this we get: $(f \circ \gamma)'(t)=0$.

But if $t \in I, 0 = (f \circ \gamma)'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))(\gamma '(t)) =  \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t)$.

---

The part I don't understand of the proof is: Why is $(f \circ \gamma)'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))(\gamma '(t))$? I don't get why this expression would be true.

Thanks.

Comment: It's the chain rule?

Comment: How is it the chain rule? @William

Comment: Isn't this just a simple application of the chain rule?

Comment: Another in a long chain of chain rule suggestions.

Comment: $f'(\gamma(t))(\gamma '(t))$ isn't $f'(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma '(t)$ @WhiteLake

Comment: The parentheses mean multiplication.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhãesThe only difference in what you wrote there was the use of () instead of $\cdot$.  Both mean multiply in this case

Comment: $f'(\gamma(t))(\gamma '(t))$ means the function $f'(\gamma(t))$ evaluated at the point $\gamma'(t)$ @Alan

Comment: @DavidP see my last comment pls

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Nope.  $f'(\gamma(t))$ is a value, not a function.  Parenthesis are overloaded notation in math.  Sometimes it means multiply, sometimes it means function input, sometimes it means ordered pairs, sometimes intervals, sometimes....If you are still having trouble with this,  try coming up with a real example for $f$ and $\gamma$

Comment: Yes, it is a function. $f'(\gamma(t))$ is the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at the point $\gamma(t)$. Thus it's not only a function but a linear map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ @Alan

Comment: What is the formal definition of $f'(s)$?

Comment: It's the Fréchet derivative of f at s, the thing is that my teacher uses the same notation for the regular derivative and for the Fréchet derivative so we kinda have to guess by the context which is which @PaulFrost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation in your formula is inconsistent.

1. $\gamma'(t)$ denotes the usual (componentwise) derivative of $\gamma$ at $t \in I$ which is a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. With $(f \circ \gamma)'(t)$ it is the same. We have $f \circ \gamma : I \to \mathbb R$, thus $(f \circ \gamma)'(t)$ denotes the usual derivative of $\gamma$ at $t \in I$ which is a real number.
2. $f'(s)$ denotes the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $s \in D$; it is a linear map $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$.

Let us now recall the chain rule. Given differentiable maps $g : U \to V$ and $h : V\to W$ between open subsets of Euclidean spaces, the Fréchet derivatives satisfy
$$(h \circ g)'(x) = h'(g(x)) \circ g'(x) . \tag{1}$$
On the RHS we have the composition of linear maps.

The problem in your formula is that the vector $\gamma'(t) \in \mathbb R^3$ does **not** denote the Fréchet derivative. For the sake of precision let us change notation and write $\overline\gamma'(t)$ for this vector and understand $\gamma'(t)$ as the Fréchet derivative $\gamma$ at $t \in I$ which is linear map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$. Similarly we write $\overline{(f \circ \gamma)}'(t) \in \mathbb R$ for the usual derivative and understand $(f \circ \gamma)'(t)$ as the Fréchet derivative which is linear map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Then we get
$$(f \circ \gamma)'(t) = f'(\gamma(t)) \circ \gamma'(t) . \tag{2}$$
What is relation between the Fréchet derivative $u'(t)$ of a map $u : I \to \mathbb R$ and its usual derivative $\overline u'(t) \in \mathbb R$? It is simply
$$\overline u'(t) = (u'(t))(1) ,\tag{3}$$
i.e. we evaluate the linear map $u'(x) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ at $1 \in \mathbb R$. This can easily be verified by writing down the definitions. Note that linear maps $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ have the property $\phi(h) = h \phi(1)$. Therefore $(2)$ gives
$$\overline{(f \circ \gamma)}'(t) = ((f \circ \gamma)'(t))(1) =  (f'(\gamma(t)) \circ \gamma'(t))(1) = f'(\gamma(t))((\gamma'(t))(1)) \\=f'(\gamma(t))(\overline \gamma'(t)). \tag{4}$$
This is your formula. If you express the linear map $f'(\gamma(t))$ by the matrix $\nabla f(\gamma(t))$, then you get

$$f'(\gamma(t))(\overline \gamma'(t)) = \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \overline\gamma'(t). \tag{5}$$
The RHS is a matrix product.

Comment: Thank you so much